# WSO2 ESB Proxy Service WSDL

Tags: wsdl, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

Am new to wso2 , i have created a proxy service which consists of Insequence with endpoint.

> Proxy service -> insequence -> endpoint (service Address in axis2).

When i try to test the Proxy service from soap UI ( with wsdl which got from management console ) , then the request format is not correct.

Following is the request msg which i see in soap UI

> ```
> <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>        <soapenv:Header/>
>        <soapenv:Body/>
>     </soapenv:Envelope>
> ```

Please let me know how to get proper WSDL for proxy service of WSO2 ESB .

Comment: repeated question. You can find additional details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248159/wso2-esb-as-a-pure-pass-through-wsdl-server-with-all-original-operations)

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating/editing the proxy service, you can select the Publish WSDL option and give the WSDL as inline text, as a URL or as a Registry Resource. In this case you can give the WSDL available at your Axis2 service.