# WSO2 ESB as a Pure Pass-Through WSDL Server with All Original Operations

Tags: web-services, wsdl, wso2, soap1.2, wso2-esb

I am a newbie in the world of WSO2 EST so my question below could be somewhat pathetic but I just wanted to ask to get help asap.

I have a WSDL of a remote web service but it is only presented in SOAP 1.2. My application can only work with SOAP 1.1 WSDL's. So I installed WSO2 ESB, added new proxy service, namely pass-through proxy, and on the "deployed services" list page, I right-clicked WSDL 1.1 on the newly created service row and used "save as" to save WSDL 1.1 version. However, the only operation available in this WSDL is "mediate" and that's all.

What I want to do is just to be able to have all operations available on the original WSDL without altering anything. I want to consume the same operations using the WSDL (1.1) served by WSO2 ESB that communicates with the remote web service using SOAP 1.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify 'Publish WSDL' options and create the WSDL accordingly. If Publish WSDL options are not specified it will show only the mediate operation.

Read the following docs to know more about this.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Adding+a+Proxy+Service#AddingaProxyService-PublishWSDLOptions

http://maharachchi.blogspot.com/2013/07/publishwsdl-option-in-wso2-esb-explained.html

---

**EDIT -** You can specify the format attribute as SOAP 1.2 in the endpoint in your proxy configuration to convert all requests to SOAP 1.2. Sample Proxy config is as follows

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="EchoProxy" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
<target>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
  <endpoint>
     <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/echo" format="soap12"/>
  </endpoint>
</target>
<publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:8282/services/echo?wsdl"/>
<description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @Nufail. Publishing WSDL with specifying in-line worked great.   
  
However, I want to ask two more questions related to this if you please:  
1. I chose "Pass-through Proxy Template" since all I want to do is to consume the service using SOAP 1.1 WSDL instead. Is this OK? Or should I go with "WSDL Based Proxy Templat"?  
  
2. The actual web service provider service just works with SOAP 1.2 but my back-end system will consume and produce requests in SOAP 1.1 via WSO2 ESB. Will WSO2 ESB do the necessary conversion and handling?  
Kind regards.

Comment: Pass-Through proxy should work ok. To convert requests to SOAP 1.2, you need to set the format attribute to SOAP 1.2. To do that you can edit your created Proxy by going to 'Design View' and in step 2, under 'Endpoint' go to edit and then to Advanced Options. In there for 'Format' select SOAP 1.2. Then all the requests going to that address will be converted to SOAP 1.2.   Or else you could just go to 'custom Proxy' when creating proxy and go to 'source view' and include the configuration as in the answer edit above.

Comment: I specify proxy information (10.0.0.3 as host and 8080 as port) in SOAP UI to establish connection. I need to supply the same proxy information  to WSO2 ESB pass-through proxy to connect to the same outside endpoint, right? Where and how do I add this information?

Comment: For SOAP UI you need to give IP and port of the ESB Proxy Service. Usually the port will be 8280 for Proxy Services. The backend url should be specified in the ESB Proxy Service. This can be specified in `<address>` element within `<endpoint>` according to above example. Then SOAP UI requests will go to ESB and the ESB will forward it to the backend service.

Comment: I guess I was not so clear. Let me try to summarize our problem once again @Nufail

All connections from the server WSO2 ESB is installed on should go through an http proxy (10.0.0.3 and port 8080). We have to supply this information to WSO2 ESB but we could not accomplish this.

We tried to edit axis2.xml, synapse.properties and tried to add http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort to some listeners and senders but no luck!